# How to use the same file java class in two different projects in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sourcesets

I need use the class `SharedClass.java` in two projects: *ProjectA* and *ProjectB*, and if I change the code of `SharedClass`, it needs to change in the other project too.

Comment: Make a library project containing this classes

Comment: And what is the next step?

Comment: refer this lib project in your main applications

Answer (score 0):

One option would be creating a library project or module, where you can provide all shared code, and include that in both projects.

Another option is adding an external source folder containing the shared classes to your projects, by adding it to the `srcDirs` in your *build.gradle* files:

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += '../../path/to/shared/code'
    }
}
```